# MongoDB Aggregate and Group by Subcategories of products

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB schema that looks like this

```
const ProductModel = new Schema({
subcategory: {
    type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref : "Subcategory",
},
product_name: {
    type: String
},
description: {
    type: String
},
price: {
    type: Number
},
});
```

And a subcategory schema:

```
const SubcategoryModel = new Schema({
    subcategoryName: {
        type: String,
    }
});
```

The input query before aggregation looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "111",
        "subcategory": {
            "_id": "456",
            "categoryName": "Sneakers",
        },
        "product_name": "Modern sneaker",
        "description": "Stylish",
        "price": 4400
    },
    {
        "_id": "222",
        "subcategory": {
            "_id": "456",
            "categoryName": "Sneakers",
        },
        "product_name": "Blue shoes",
        "description": "Vived colors",
        "price": 7500
    },
    {
        "_id": "333",
        "subcategory": {
            "_id": "123",
            "categoryName": "Jackets",
            "__v": 0
        },
        "product_name": "Modern jacket",
        "description": "Stylish",
        "price": 4400
    },
    }
]
```

The final result of the query should look like this:

```
{
   "Sneakers":[
      {
         "product_name":"Modern sneaker",
         "description":"Stylish",
         "price":"4400"
      },
      {
         "product_name":"Blue shoes",
         "description":"Vived colors",
         "price":"7500"
      },
      "Jackets":{
         "...."
      }
   ]
}
```

Subcategory before aggregation:

```
"subcategories": [
  {
    "_id": "123",
    "categoryName": "Jackets",
    
  },
  {
    "_id": "456",
    "categoryName": "Sneakers",
    
  }
]
```

I'm trying to populate the subcategory, And then group the products by their subcategoryName field.

Comment: How is your data? Can you please provide an input example?

Comment: Sorry, I Just did, refresh the page :]

Comment: `sneakers` and `Jackets` are values from `subcategoryName`?

Comment: just added an input example and an output one.
yes both are values of subcategoryName.

Comment: And can you add an example of Subcategory?

Comment: Sorry for the mess, just updated the examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this aggregation query:

- First `$lookup` to do the join between `Product` and `Subcategory` creating the array `subcategories`.
- Then deconstructs the array using `$unwind`.
- `$group` by the name of subproduct adding the entire object using `$$ROOT`.
- The passes the fields you want using `$project`.
- And `replaceRoot` to get key value into arrays as `Sneakers` and `Jackets`.

```
db.Product.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Subcategory",
      "localField": "subcategory.categoryName",
      "foreignField": "categoryName",
      "as": "subcategories"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$subcategories"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$subcategories.categoryName",
      "data": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "data": {
        "product_name": 1,
        "description": 1,
        "price": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$arrayToObject": [
          [
            {
              "k": "$_id",
              "v": "$data"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vg4s3j03wJX)

With your provided data, result is:

```
[
  {
    "Sneakers": [
      {
        "description": "Stylish",
        "price": 4400,
        "product_name": "Modern sneaker"
      },
      {
        "description": "Vived colors",
        "price": 7500,
        "product_name": "Blue shoes"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Jackets": [
      {
        "description": "Stylish",
        "price": 4400,
        "product_name": "Modern jacket"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Great, your solution sure works fine, but one extra things I ran into, 
Giving that the subcategory is an ObjectID 
When i try to provide the subcategory._id or _id it gives me this error
$lookup argument 'localField' must be a string, found localField: { $toObjectId: "subcategory._id" }: object

you can check my setup i did over your solution in this link
https://mongoplayground.net/p/JH4kUSZWATC

Comment: If field is ObjectId you don't need to use `$toObjectId`. Also if you want to parse to ObjectId I think [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rRT5bGOGWdu) using `pipeline` should works.

Comment: Thank you man, this problem wasted a lot of my time, you saved it ;]